# Add data to post edit page, when post is published

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, dashboard, post-editor

I need to customize the "post edit page", for a custom post_type, but to keep things simple let's say it's on the post_type post for now.

When the post status is published, I need to run a PHP script that fetches some data from my database, based on the post_id of the current post.

**Question:**
Where do I add this script??

Thanks..

[image]

Comment: Search for `add_meta_box()`. This function is the key to add custom areas to the edit screen and inside this can you handle your custom requirements.

Comment: Was only short, no specific help for you. But if you like, below is the short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `add_meta_box()`. This function is the key to add custom areas to the edit screen and inside this can you handle your custom requirements.